# How do I read the documentation syntax for PostgreSQL commands?

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a table in database A from several tables in database B. I went to the PostgreSQL's documentation [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html) to figure out how and the documentation for the command is decorated with brackets, bars, curly brackets, parenthesis, bold words and all-caps words, etc.

What do all of these symbols denote about the command and could somebody please show how I would read the documentation to determine what the correct syntax for creating a table in database A from a select query on a table in database B.

The internet has been a great resource for basic PostgreSQL formulas to copy and paste, but I'd like to move beyond copying and pasting formulas that just magically work.

Comment: `{ a | b }` means *a* or *b*, `[ stuff ]` means that *stuff* is optional, bold is for something you have to fill in, fixed width is for literal parts of the syntax. http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/notation.html

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram

Comment: `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...`

Comment: @muistooshort Please post as an answer? Otherwise I'd have to basically copy and paste what you said, and that gives me the twitches.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The conventions are covered in the [**Conventions**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/notation.html) chapter of the manual:

> The following conventions are used in the synopsis of a command: brackets (`[` and `]`) indicate optional parts. (In the synopsis of a Tcl command, question marks (`?`) are used instead, as is usual in Tcl.) Braces (`{` and `}`) and vertical lines (`|`) indicate that you must choose one alternative. Dots (`...`) mean that the preceding element can be repeated.

So `{ a | b }` means *a* or *b* and `[ stuff ]` means that *stuff* is optional. Furthermore, bold text in an example command represents something you need to fill in and fixed-width text is a literal part of the syntax in question.