# What does the SQL example syntax mean?

Tags: sql, syntax

I was wondering about notation in the [documentation of PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html).

[ ], { }, [ ... ], [ , ... ], ( ) etc...

You can see these signs from SQL query example etc.

What do these signs mean?

Comment: [ is a square bracket, ( is a bracket, { is a curly bracket .... so I believe

Comment: Do you mean literally the names of the characters? Conventionally `{}` braces, `[]` brackets, `()` parentheses. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bracket; at this point it isn't really a programming question.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you for reply. I'm reading this SQL page https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html and i wondering brackets means.. Can you know me that means?

Comment: Then this is probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/26087556/3001761. Note that documentation itself explains the notation used: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/notation.html, and that you should [edit] the question to clarify what you're actually asking.

Comment: That's explained in the manual right at the beginning: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/notation.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read the documentation syntax for postgresql commands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26087556/how-do-i-read-the-documentation-syntax-for-postgresql-commands)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[square brackets]` indicate optional parameters. You can include any number of these, or none.

`(parentheses)` are simply part of the SQL code, and does not indicate any deeper meaning in the documentation.

`{curly braces}` and verical lines `|` indicate that there are a limited amount of options to choose, and you must choose one alternative or another.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's [actual question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46990626/what-is-call-this-sign?noredirect=1#comment80928308_46990626), I'd recommend waiting for clarification before answering unclear questions.

Comment: @jonrsharpe - Actually, the question wasn't unclear at all. It's just that the way it was written, it turned out as a different question than the one intended.

Comment: I have edited my answer to target the intended question now. Hopefully it becomes clearer.

Answer (score 1):

`[]` - There are called "square brackets"
`{}` - These are called "curly brackets".
`()` - These are simply called "brackets".

I hope I answered your question?

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's [actual question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46990626/what-is-call-this-sign?noredirect=1#comment80928308_46990626), I'd recommend waiting for clarification before answering unclear questions.

Answer (score 0):

[ is a square bracket, ( is a round bracket, { is a curly bracket .... so I believe

Use the word left or right in front of them. The ones above are left

Round bracket also known as parenthesis

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's [actual question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46990626/what-is-call-this-sign?noredirect=1#comment80928308_46990626), I'd recommend waiting for clarification before answering unclear questions.